# Change character in matrix - ADFGVX Cipher

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm doing a **ADFGVX Cipher Encoder** and when I give my key and plaintext to encode, my cipher dont completely fill in. I will try to explain better.

For example my key is `WHISKY`and I have this cipher `FFDXAAFAGFFDAGFF`.

When I make the matrix with my cipher, what happen is, because my cipher is not divisible by the key lenght, it automatically put a 0 in that space, but I want to put a character in that place instead, like "0" = "X"

**I put here a table to show whats happening:**

| W | H | I | S | K | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | D | X | A | A |
| F | A | G | F | F | D |
| A | G | F | F | 0 | 0 |

**Here I will put what my code does:**

```
def Encrypt_Plaintext():
    mensagemoriginal = input("Introduza a mensagem a encriptar: ")
    mensagemoriginal = mensagemoriginal.upper()
    mensagemcifrada = ""
    for l in mensagemoriginal:
        if l in keysquare:
            mensagemcifrada += (keysquare[l])
    return mensagemcifrada
```

```
def Encrypt_Setup(key, ciphertext):
    width = len(key)
    height = math.ceil(len(ciphertext)/width)
    tabela = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
    linhas = 0
    colunas = 0
    index = 0
    while (linhas < height):
        while(colunas < width):
            if(index == len(ciphertext)):
                break
            tabela[linhas][colunas] = ciphertext[index]
            index += 1
            colunas += 1
        linhas += 1
        colunas = 0
    return tabela
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple change allows you to have X where you now have 0, if that's what you want:

```
tabela = [['X' for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
```